# Tool or website for naming small organic molecules

Tags: support

I've been away from chemistry since after school, but once in a while I get back for sheer curiosity.

Today, I stumbled about $\ce{HCONH_2}$, but couldn't find anything about it without knowing its name.

So I'm in want of a tool or website for naming small organic molecules.

Comment: Umm, triviality aside, meta is for questions regarding the site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At risk of sounding rude, have you tried Google? Typing ["HCONH2"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hconh2) directly into it gives me the name. I'm not trying to be patronising, but it does work pretty well for small-ish molecules. You can even find the name if you mangle the chemical formula, e.g. ["NH2CHO"](https://www.google.com/search?q=nh2cho) or ["H2NCOH"](https://www.google.com/search?q=h2ncoh).

[image: Google search results]

Alternatively, you can try [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/):

[image: PubChem search results]

Comment: To be honest: no. I've tried all names for it that came to mind on wikipedia, instead.

Comment: Give it a try next time, then ;)

Comment: PubChem is the answer I was looking for. Even got result on H2NCOF.

Comment: I tried to put the _preferred IUPAC name (PIN)_ for all **small** organic compounds on Wikipedia. If you find something is missing, please give me a hint in chat.